# problems with robot state publisher

Tags: robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am trying to install robote_state_publisher using the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher & installation source https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/robot_model but after the installation the node is not appearing any help???? doing it for electric

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56218/problems-with-robot-state-publisher/) by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any reason why you can't just apt-get it? If you need to build from source, list the steps that you did and which one failed.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0